# how to add or operation for fixing a code for creating a new variable

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to modify the following code:

```
library(dplyr)
df1<-df7 %>% 
  group_by(SAMPN,PERNO) %>% 
  mutate(loop = lag(cumsum(TPURP== "(2) All other home activities" ), default = 1))
```

I want to loop change when  it gets to (2) All other home activities or (1) Working at home (for pay)  or (24) Loop trip. just (24) Loop trip is a little different, it has its own index so in each row whose TPURP is (24) Loop trip  index of loop change and change again in next row

```
 dput(Nontest[2893:2913,1:4])
structure(list(SAMPN = c(1626, 1626, 1626, 1626, 1626, 1626, 
1626, 1626, 1639, 1639, 1639, 1639, 1639, 1639, 1639, 1640, 1640, 
1640, 1643, 1643, 1643), PERNO = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 1, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), PLANO = c(5, 6, 3, 4, 5, 
2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4), TPURP = structure(c(22L, 
9L, 22L, 13L, 1L, 5L, 19L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 22L, 22L, 3L, 13L, 2L, 
20L, 15L, 2L, 13L, 13L, 2L), .Label = c("(1) Working at home (for pay)", 
"(2) All other home activities", "(3) Work/Job", "(4) All other activities at work", 
"(5) Attending class", "(6) All other activities at school", 
"(7) Change type of transportation/transfer", "(8) Dropped off passenger", 
"(9) Picked up passenger", "(10) Other, specify - transportation", 
"(11) Work/Business related", "(12) Service Private Vehicle", 
"(13) Routine Shopping", "(14) Shopping for major purchases", 
"(15) Household errands", "(16) Personal Business", "(17) Eat meal outside of home", 
"(18) Health care", "(19) Civic/Religious activities", "(20) Recreation/Entertainment", 
"(21) Visit friends/relative", "(24) Loop trip", "(97) Other, specify"
), class = "factor")), row.names = c(9914L, 9915L, 9916L, 9917L, 
9918L, 9919L, 9920L, 9922L, 9974L, 9975L, 9976L, 9977L, 9978L, 
9979L, 9980L, 9981L, 9982L, 9983L, 9992L, 9993L, 9994L), class = "data.frame")
```

output

```
    SAMPN PERNO PLANO                           TPURP        loop
9914  1626     1     5                  (24) Loop trip         1
9915  1626     1     6         (9) Picked up passenger         2
9916  1626     2     3                  (24) Loop trip         1
9917  1626     2     4           (13) Routine Shopping         2
9918  1626     2     5   (1) Working at home (for pay)         2
9919  1626     3     2             (5) Attending class         1
9920  1626     3     3 (19) Civic/Religious activities         1
9922  1626     4     2             (5) Attending class         1
9974  1639     1     2                    (3) Work/Job         1
9975  1639     1     3   (2) All other home activities         1
9976  1639     1     4                  (24) Loop trip         2
9977  1639     2     2                  (24) Loop trip         1
9978  1639     2     3                    (3) Work/Job         2
9979  1639     2     4           (13) Routine Shopping         2
9980  1639     2     5   (2) All other home activities         2
9981  1640     1     2   (20) Recreation/Entertainment         1 
9982  1640     1     3          (15) Household errands         1
9983  1640     1     4   (2) All other home activities         1
9992  1643     1     2           (13) Routine Shopping         1
9993  1643     1     3           (13) Routine Shopping         1
9994  1643     1     4   (2) All other home activities         1
```

I just put the out put that I want to have. it would be great if you fix my code rather than new method. but if it can not be fixed plz give other method

more data for explaining (24) Loop trip

```
structure(list(SAMPN = c(1626, 1626, 1626, 1626, NA, 1626), PERNO = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, NA, 2), PLANO = c(4, 5, 6, 7, NA, 2), TPURP = structure(c(22L, 
22L, 9L, 2L, NA, 22L), .Label = c("(1) Working at home (for pay)", 
"(2) All other home activities", "(3) Work/Job", "(4) All other activities at work", 
"(5) Attending class", "(6) All other activities at school", 
"(7) Change type of transportation/transfer", "(8) Dropped off passenger", 
"(9) Picked up passenger", "(10) Other, specify - transportation", 
"(11) Work/Business related", "(12) Service Private Vehicle", 
"(13) Routine Shopping", "(14) Shopping for major purchases", 
"(15) Household errands", "(16) Personal Business", "(17) Eat meal outside of home", 
"(18) Health care", "(19) Civic/Religious activities", "(20) Recreation/Entertainment", 
"(21) Visit friends/relative", "(24) Loop trip", "(97) Other, specify"
), class = "factor")), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), groups = structure(list(
    SAMPN = c(1626, 1626, NA), PERNO = c(1, 2, NA), .rows = list(
        1:4, 6L, 5L)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

output

```
 SAMPN PERNO PLANO TPURP                             loop   
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <fct>                             
1  1626     1     4 (24) Loop trip                     1
2  1626     1     5 (24) Loop trip                     2
3  1626     1     6 (9) Picked up passenger            3
4  1626     1     7 (2) All other home activities      3
5    NA    NA    NA NA                                 NA
6  1626     2     2 (24) Loop trip                     1
```

each loop trip has own index

Comment: What are you trying to do and also can you show your expected output?

Comment: loop is counting trips for each PERNO(person index) in each SAMPN(household index), it starts from 1 and the end is one of the TPURP values that I mentioned in my code

Comment: I don't understand the logic your `loop` counter follows. Why is 5th row `(1) Working at home (for pay) ` 2 ? When does it change from 1 to 2 ?

Comment: any loop trip has own index. if index of loop trip is i then any trip after that is i+1 and it is gonna be i+1 until (2) All other home activities  or (1) Working at home (for pay) .

Comment: if trip start with (1) Working at home (for pay)  or (2) All other home activities  then loop is gonna change until (1) Working at home (for pay) or (2) All other home activities

Comment: @RonakShah is it make sense?

Comment: if it starts with arbitrary trip, loop will be 1 until (1) Working at home (for pay) or (2) All other home activities or  (24) Loop trip

Comment: Still not clear to me. why is loop 2 for row number 9978 to 9980 ? `Work/Job` and `Routine Shopping` do not come in any of those 3 categories.

Comment: after  (24) Loop trip , index of loop change. each  (24) Loop trip  has own index

Comment: okay and why does it reset again at 1 on next line 9981 `Recreation/Entertainment`  ?

Comment: because person change. (PERNO)

Answer (score 0):

We create a vector (`vals`) of all the activities where we want to increment the count, `group_by` `SAMPN` and `PERNO` and create a `loop` count for every group using `lag` and `cummax`.

```
vals <- c("(2) All other home activities", "(24) Loop trip", 
          "(1) Working at home (for pay)")

library(dplyr)

df7 %>% 
  group_by(SAMPN,PERNO) %>% 
  mutate(loop = cummax(lag(1 + (TPURP %in% vals), default = 1)))


#   SAMPN PERNO PLANO TPURP                            loop
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <fct>                           <dbl>
# 1  1626     1     5 (24) Loop trip                      1
# 2  1626     1     6 (9) Picked up passenger             2
# 3  1626     2     3 (24) Loop trip                      1
# 4  1626     2     4 (13) Routine Shopping               2
# 5  1626     2     5 (1) Working at home (for pay)       2
# 6  1626     3     2 (5) Attending class                 1
# 7  1626     3     3 (19) Civic/Religious activities     1
# 8  1626     4     2 (5) Attending class                 1
# 9  1639     1     2 (3) Work/Job                        1
#10  1639     1     3 (2) All other home activities       1
# … with 11 more rows
```

Comment: @hghg yes and also to two other activities you mentioned. This gives expected output at least for the data that you have shared.

Comment: (24) Loop trip is different, it takes its own index but 2 others will change until to get one of those TPURP.

Comment: it works for "(2) All other home activities",   "(1) Working at home (for pay)" but not  (24) Loop trip,

Comment: I will put some data and explain (24) Loop trip again, I hope u can modify your code

Comment: @hghg Can you try `df7 %>% 
  group_by(SAMPN,PERNO) %>% 
  mutate(loop = lag(cumsum(TPURP %in% vals) + 1, default = 1))` this is similar to your initial attempt. Does this give you the output needed ?

Comment: the point is "(24) Loop trip" is different than 2 others.  maybe I should ask differently

Comment: Not my downvote but I am unable to understand. Maybe someone else would help you.

Comment: your code works for 2 other TPURP but for (24) Loop trip does not work. each (24) Loop trip has own index.

Comment: plz look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57987124/how-to-change-a-column-with-respect-of-another-column-and-a-group