# how to change a column with respect of another column and a group

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 2 columns

```
 PERNO      TPURP       loop
 1      Loop trip     1
 1      Loop trip     2
 1      home          2
 1      shopping      2
 2      work          1
 2      Loop trip     2
 2      school        2
 3      Looptrip      1
 4      work          1
```

for each perno if TPURP== Loop trip I want to add 1 to loop after that row.

for each PERNO if  Loop trip is exactly in next row of another Loop trip we don't add 1 to first one but we do for second one.

output

```
 PERNO      TPURP       loop
 1      Loop trip     1
 1      Loop trip     2
 1      home          3
 1      shopping      3
 2      work          1
 2      Loop trip     2
 2      school        3
 3      Looptrip      1
 4      work          1
```

data

```
structure(list(PERNO = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), TPURP = structure(c(8L, 
1L, 22L, 22L, 9L, 2L), .Label = c("(1) Working at home (for pay)", 
"(2) All other home activities", "(3) Work/Job", "(4) All other activities at work", 
"(5) Attending class", "(6) All other activities at school", 
"(7) Change type of transportation/transfer", "(8) Dropped off passenger", 
"(9) Picked up passenger", "(10) Other, specify - transportation", 
"(11) Work/Business related", "(12) Service Private Vehicle", 
"(13) Routine Shopping", "(14) Shopping for major purchases", 
"(15) Household errands", "(16) Personal Business", "(17) Eat meal outside of home", 
"(18) Health care", "(19) Civic/Religious activities", "(20) Recreation/Entertainment", 
"(21) Visit friends/relative", "(24) Loop trip", "(97) Other, specify"
), class = "factor"), loop = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Why are `work` and `school` also increasing?

Comment: I am really sorry , loop trip is not increasing, a row after that is increasing. plz see edit

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`, we can `group_by` `PERNO` and increment the value of `loop` after the last occurrence of `"Loop trip"` in the group.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(PERNO) %>%
  mutate(loop1 = ifelse(any(TPURP == "Loop trip") & 
            row_number() > max(which(TPURP == "Loop trip")),loop + 1, loop))

# PERNO TPURP      loop loop1
#  <int> <fct>     <int> <dbl>
#1     1 Loop trip     1     1
#2     1 Loop trip     2     2
#3     1 home          2     3
#4     1 shopping      2     3
#5     2 work          1     1
#6     2 Loop trip     2     2
#7     2 school        2     3
#8     3 Looptrip      1     1
#9     4 work          1     1
```

This returns a warning message if for any group there is no `"Loop trip"` but it can be ignored.

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(PERNO = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L), 
TPURP = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 6L), .Label = c("home", 
"Loop trip", "Looptrip", "school", "shopping", "work"), class = "factor"), 
loop = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

---

Or we can use `grepl`/`grep` to partial match instead of exact match as mentioned by @Sotos. On the updated dataset we can do

```
df %>% 
  group_by(PERNO) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(loop1 = ifelse(any(grepl('Loop', TPURP)) & 
     row_number() > max(grep('Loop', TPURP)), loop + 1, loop))

#   PERNO TPURP                          loop loop1
#   <dbl> <fct>                         <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1 (8) Dropped off passenger         1     1
#2     1 (1) Working at home (for pay)     1     1
#3     1 (24) Loop trip                    2     2
#4     1 (24) Loop trip                    2     2
#5     1 (9) Picked up passenger           2     3
#6     1 (2) All other home activities     2     3
```

Comment: it doesn't change loop1 in my data, and I get this warning: In max(which(TPURP == "Loop trip")) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

Comment: loop1==loop in my data

Comment: @hghg Use "Loop trip" exactly the way it is in your data. Is it "Loop trip" or "Looptrip" or "Loop Trip" or something else ?

Comment: Just use `grep`...this should work `df %>%
     group_by(PERNO) %>%
     mutate(loop1 = ifelse(any(grepl('Loop', TPURP)) &
                       row_number() > max(which(grepl('Loop', TPURP))), loop + 1, loop))`

Comment: @RonakShah I use my data information but same problem

Comment: @Sotos again gives me same column as loop, and its "(24) Loop trip" if its matter

Comment: @hghg Can you test it on the data I have posted in the answer. Does it give you the same output as me?

Comment: it works on your data, let me to put my data in the question

Comment: @hghg If you use the `grep`answer updated , it works for your data right? `df %>% 
  group_by(PERNO) %>%
  mutate(loop1 = ifelse(any(grepl('Loop', TPURP)) & 
                          row_number() > max(grep('Loop', TPURP)), loop + 1, loop))
`

Comment: Works for me for your new example

Comment: do you have `plyr` loaded so `mutate` function might be masked. Use `dplyr::mutate` and see if there is any change. As mentioned earlier, it works for me on the data which you have shared.

Comment: so weird I don't know how it works for u guys on my data .I tried all methods and loop and loop1 is exactly the same. max(df$loop-df$loop1)=0